# Weird character when writing to file in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to append the url part that comes after the ".php?" to a new line in a text file, and then print out everything in that file, but I'm getting a weird character after every time I run fwrite().

Here's my code:

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {
        $pageURL .= "s";
    }
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}
$pattern = "/http:\/\/www.mywebsite.com\/firstphpthing.php\?(.*)/";
preg_match($pattern,curPageUrl(),$matches);
$content = $matches[1];
if(!file_exists("testfile.txt")) {
    $f = fopen("testfile.txt","w");
    fwrite($f,"");
    fclose($f);
}
$f = fopen('testfile.txt','a');
fwrite($f,PHP_EOL . $content);
fclose($f);
$f = fopen('testfile.txt','r') or die("can't open file");
while ($line = fgets($f)) {
    $line = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $line);
    if(!preg_match("/^\s+$/",$line,$matches)) {
        echo $line;
    }
}
fclose($f);
php?>
```

When I test it by refreshing http://www.mywebsite.com/firstphpthing.php?test a bunch of times, it gives me this:

> test[F test[F test[F test[F test[F test[F test[F test[F test[F test

rather than seeing them each on a new line, I've tried copy-pasting that little box into google and it says it's "%1B", which corresponds to escape in url encoding, but I'm not sure how to get rid of it (also, I have no idea where the "[F" part comes from).

It might also be the platform that I'm running this on (000webhost.com), that might have configured something in a weird way?

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're copying a link from somewhere, some weird whitespace characters could blend in,which in turn can cause problems. Try hand typing the link to make sure you get no white space. Also try trimming the url before you return it, it might help.

```
return trim($pageURL);
```

I'm sure this would qualify as a comment, more than an answer, but since I can't comment and I think it might be helpful, I'll leave it here.